# PIVOT query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am getting an error with the below sql statement. Error reads:

> Error in FROM clause: near 'SELECT'
>   Unable to parse query
>
> Error Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Any ideas as to why?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
 FROM dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN (SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks]) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: I must be going blind, I am unable to see where the bracket should go. Added it before the AS PivotTable but still get the same message

Comment: I am using SQL Expresss

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
 FROM dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks 
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN (SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks])) AS PivotTable;   try this.

Comment: my statement now reads 
SELECT        *
FROM            (SELECT        [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
                          FROM            dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks) AS SourceTable PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN (SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks])) AS PivotTable;
Ad I am still getting the same error message

Comment: its not a bracket that you are missing, but a right parenthesis at the end

Comment: is your [Final Week] contains space in it?

Comment: I have tried this but still the same
SELECT        *
FROM            (SELECT        [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
                          FROM            dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks) AS SourceTable PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN (SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks])) AS PivotTable);

Pulling my hair out now, and its probably something so simple

Comment: SELECT        *
FROM            (SELECT        [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
                          FROM            dbo.DeptSummary) AS SourceTable PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN ([11])) AS PivotTable;
This works, but as soon as I replace the [11] with my Select statement, it stops working

Comment: What is [11]???

Comment: [11] is a new column name after the PIVOT has taken place. What I have is weeks in a column, then pivoting it so the weeks then become columns, if that makes sense, but I only need 10 weeks, starting from the current week. Thats what the SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks] does, it selects the 10 weeks

Comment: So basically my IN statement needs to be [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]
but next week it needs to be [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21]
Thats what the SELECT statement does

Answer (score 1):

Try to use explicit `WeekNum` and add closing bracket in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
 FROM dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) AS PivotTable
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to use dynamic version of pivot:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);
  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ' , ' + CONCAT('[', CONVERT(varchar(10),  t.WeekNum), ']')
      from dbo.[10Weeks] t 
      order by 1
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')

select  @sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
         SELECT [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total
         FROM dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks
    ) AS SourceTable 
    PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS PivotTable'   

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: The statement works the way you have written it but the weeks change week on week. I am trying to do a rolling 10 weeks so it needs to be [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20] this week but next week it needs to be [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21]

Comment: Well when i execute it it works, but it won't let me save it as a view. I get error message: Incorrect syntax near the word 'declare'

Comment: Managed to use it as a Stored Procedure, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to give some empty value for Final Week

```
  SELECT [Order], Dept, Area,'' as [Final Week], Total
     FROM dbo.DeptSummary10Weeks
```

Just try following way...

```
Declare @var nvarchar(max)
Select @var = coalesce(@var +',','') + cast(WeekNum as nvarchar(20)) from dbo.[10Weeks]    
FOR [Final Week] IN ('+@var+') AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks but the statement works if I change to this
SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Order], Dept, Area, [Final Week], Total FROM dbo.DeptSummary) AS SourceTable PIVOT (Sum(Total) FOR [Final Week] IN ([11])) AS PivotTable;

Comment: but when I change [11] to SELECT WeekNum FROM dbo.[10Weeks] thats when I get the message